# How to build a nested check box grid in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to build a grid of checkbox elements as shown below.

[image]

I know how to build this with normal `jquery`. How does one build this as an `Ember` component?

[Here is the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/deyuk/4/edit?html,js,output) of building it with `jquery` and `handlebars`.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what the checkboxes are supposed to do? Do you want the count of each checkbox? Do they each represent some kind of value?

Comment: Each checkbox represents a boolean identified by the row and column number. Example - 7 days a week as columns and 5 tasks per day as rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready-to-use Ember Checkbox class: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Checkbox.html

It works like other Ember views.  The bit about "grid" is mixing together HTML/CSS styling concerns, which have nothing to do with Ember.

Comment: I do know about the checkbox. My question was more about how one could build a grid as a component.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on how to create an Ember Component: `http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/`  Show your best attempt and then ask for help with any problems you may have.